# Rails best way to access childs siblings in a parent-child relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have these models:

```
class Folder < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :files, -> { reorder_descending }, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :not_deleted_files, -> { not_deleted.reorder_descending }, class_name: 'File'
end


class File < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :folder

  scope :not_deleted, -> { where('deleted_at IS NULL ') }

  scope :reorder_ascending, -> { reorder('enactment_date ASC, finding_date ASC, id ASC') }
  scope :reorder_descending, -> { reorder('enactment_date DESC, finding_date DESC, id DESC') }

  def not_deleted_files
    folder.not_deleted_files
  end
end
```

Now i have a folder and I iterate over all it's files. 
In the File class I have a lot of methods that are using the not_deleted_files method. Every time this method is used, a new query is fired. Even though they all have the same parent (Folder).

Also the queries are cached, I think there should be a way to prevent them at all.

Comment: try using `inverse_of`. Let me know if something has improved.

Comment: @GaganGupta
can i define the inverse_of on both has_many relations on the folder class? It would certainly be correct for the first one (has_many :files), but not quite for the second (has_many :not_deleted_files) as there is no inverse for this one.

Comment: It should work for both of them.. try it

Comment: I added inverse_of to both, now each file has the same folder instance. Thank you!

Comment: Cool!
I am writing it as an answer, you can mark it as accepted. I'm glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `inverse_of` as Rails can optimize object loading so `parent_object` and `child_object.parent` will reference the same object in memory, instead of loading another copy of the same record.

I am glad it helped. :)